# OAuth2 server [Node.JS]

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, google-smart-home

Which library can I use to implement OAuth2 authorization and refresh token in NodeJS for Google Smart Home Action? I tried using passport-oauth2 and passport-google-oauth20 but cant get my desired results

Comment: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs ??

Answer (score 1):

The [account linking guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2?oauth=code) indicates the features your OAuth server needs to implement in order to successfully link users of your smart home Action with Google. Mainly, you need have a server that implements the **authorization** and **token exchange** endpoints for the user accounts you maintain.

The libraries you have mentioned seem to assist with implementing **client-side authentication** of requests based on various identity providers rather than an OAuth server. It seems the developer of Passport also maintains a companion package called [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) which may be able to help you.

***NOTE:*** I cannot vouch for whether this library will seamlessly integrate with Google Assistant account linking. Simply pointing out the infrastructure required for an OAuth server vs. client.